# Not able to call functions from another JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Got this really simple problem that I just can't figure a solution to. I am not able to call a function from another javascript file in nodejs.

My main file:

```
var Binance = require('./binance.js');

//later in the file
app.post('/createBotOrder', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("in");
    console.log(Binance);
    console.log(Binance.sum(1, 2));
    console.log("in 2");
});
```

My secondary file:

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.sum = function(a,b) { return a+b };
    this.multiply = function(a,b) { return a*b };
    //etc
}
```

Output:

```
in
[Function]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to export as an object with your function as a property.

```
module.exports = { myFunc : function () { //stuff } }
```

Then in the file where you import myFunc

```
const Binance = require('./binance.js')
Binance.myFunc()
```

Answer (score 3):

`Binance` is a constructor function. It doesn't have a `sum` property.

When you **call** `Binance`, then it assigns a function to the `sum` property of `this`.

You aren't calling `Binance` at all.

Thus:

```
var Binance = require('./binance.js');
var my_binance = new Binance();

//later in the file
app.post('/createBotOrder', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("in");
    console.log(my_binance);
    console.log(my_binance.sum(1, 2));
    console.log("in 2");
});
```

---

That said, it doesn't make sense for `Binance` to be a constructor function. There's nothing to distinguish one instance of it from another. You might as well export a simple object:

```
module.exports = {
    this.sum = function(a,b) { return a+b },
    this.multiply = function(a,b) { return a*b },
};
```

and then:

```
var binance = require('./binance.js');

//later in the file
app.post('/createBotOrder', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("in");
    console.log(binance);
    console.log(binance.sum(1, 2));
    console.log("in 2");
});
```

Note that variable names starting with a capital letter are traditionally reserved for constructor functions. Since it isn't a constructor function, I renamed it.